How to make a Leaflet GridLayer interactive
So I make vector tiles with geojson-vt, using the Leaflet GridLayer. The vector tiles work just fine. But I want to make it interactive. In the Leaflet (1.9.4) docs mentioned that GridLayers have many methods, some of which are inherited from Evented, among many other methods. So I assume, that GridLayer would work with on(), addEventListener(), etc methods. But it doesn't.
I test the GridLayer method and it works just fine, but any other method that inherited from other classes are not working.
const CustomGridLayer = L.GridLayer.extend({
    createTile: (coords) => {
        // tile functions here
    });

const myLayer = new CustomGridLayer();

// setOpacity is the original GridLayer method, and it works
// so I believe, it's the correct way to use the method
customGridLayer.setOpacity(0.5)

// on() 'inherited' method not working
customGridLayer.on("click", () => { console.log("clicked") })

// and addEventListener() also not working
customGridLayer.addEventListener("click", () => { console.log("clicked") })
    

What confused me are those method are written in the docs.
EDIT:
Just try this line and it's working (just for tileload event)
customGridLayer.on('tileload', function(event) {
    console.log('Tile loaded:', event.coords);
});


See https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/blob/master/docs/demo-points-icons.html#L83 .
